# How to make CUDA dll that can be used in C# application?

Tags: c#, c, cuda, nvidia

It would be good if you could give me a brief tutorial instead of a few words.

My CUDA application is working as I wanted. Now, the problem is how to export CUDA code to C# as I would like to make front end and everything else in C#.

From this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w

I know how to make a library in C language that can be imported into C# application as Win32 dll.

But my question is, **how to make CUDA application dll (or some other extension) that can be shipped to C# and used from C# application?**
It would be good if there is somewhere tutorial for CUDA like the one for C library to C# app(above link).

I am using Win7 64 bit, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Cuda Toolikt 5.0 and NSight 2.2.012313

Comment: You may be interested in this [Dr. Dobbs article](http://v4.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/print?articleId=232601605&siteSectionName=).

Comment: There are a few attempts of making C# interfaces to CUDA available. Maybe anyone of those can help you move forward: [managedCUDA](http://managedcuda.codeplex.com/) and [CUDAfy.NET](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Well, I would prefare just dll import, without anything added if it is possible. I want to keep it simple. But thank you for the advice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ManagedCUDA](http://managedcuda.codeplex.com) is perfect for this type of thing. First you need to follow the instructions in the [documentation](http://managedcuda.codeplex.com/documentation) to set up your Visual Studio Project.

Here is an example of a solution:

test.cu (compiles to test.ptx)

```
#if !defined(__CUDACC__)
#define __CUDACC__
#include <host_config.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <math_functions.h>
#endif

extern "C"
{
    __global__ void test(float * data)
    {
        float a = data[0];
        float b = data[1];
        float c = data[2];

        data[0] = max(a, max(b, c));
    }
}
```

and here is the C# code:

```
private static void Test()
{
    using (CudaContext ctx = new CudaContext())
    {

        CudaDeviceVariable<float> d = new CudaDeviceVariable<float>(3);
        CUmodule module = ctx.LoadModulePTX("test.ptx");
        CudaKernel kernel = new CudaKernel("test", module, ctx)
            {
                GridDimensions = new dim3(1, 1),
                BlockDimensions = new dim3(1, 1)
            };
        kernel.Run(d.DevicePointer);
    }
}
```

This is just a proof of concept, the device memory is not even initialized and the result is not read but is enough to illustrate how to do it.

You have several options how to distribute your application. In this case i opted for compiling the .cu file into PTX and load it inside the C# project from filesystem.
You could also embed the PTX as a resource directly into your C# application.
You could also compile into a cubin and load or embed that instead of PTX.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will take a look when I catch some time and give you points if it works. Thanks